# How can this code be written in one line? How can it be written more pythonically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used a nested for loop to create a dictionary which holds a list of elements. But, this feels clunky for Python. How can it be written more Pythonically? Is there an elegant way to write this in one line?

```py
d1 = {}
for ds in datasets:
    d1[ds] = {}
    for mutType in mutTypes:
        d1[ds][mutType] = []
```

Comment: `d1 = {ds: {mut_type: [] for mut_type in mutTypes} for ds in datasets`

Comment: This code is perfectly pythonic. Pythonic doesn't mean "written on one line"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I take Pythonic to mean very readable. Would you not?

Comment: @StephenRauch, Thanks!

Comment: @RobS I take it to mean conforming to the idiomatic way things are done in Python. For loops are very idiomatic. And yes, that implies readability being heavily valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this together as two nested dictionary comprehensions. I not sure I would call it more pythonic that the loops which are quite readable, but I wouldn't argue with someone who preferred it:

```
datasets = ['a', 'b', 'c']
mutTypes = ['x', 'y', 'z']

d1 = {k:{mutType: [] for mutType in mutTypes} for k in datasets}
```

**Result**

```
{'a': {'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []},
 'b': {'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []},
 'c': {'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There usually isn't a need to declare the data structure in advance in Python. What I would do is to use a `defaultdict` as my container, and use it directly.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

# Use d1 directly
d1[ds_1][mutType_1].append(123)
d1[ds_2][mutType_2].append(234)

# If you wish to strip out the nested defaultdict after, you can do something like this:
d2 = {key:dict(value) for key, value in d1.items()}
```

As always, it depends on what you're trying to do. Using `d1` as such means it won't raise a `KeyError` when you're using keys not in `datasets` and/or `mutTypes`.